# How to apply Sobolev inequalities?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm struggling with an application of Sobolev inequalities in Evans' book.

He presents his argument like this:

> For $4<p<5$ we have $2(p-1)=2(p-4)+6=2(p-4)+ 2^*$ and therefore
>   $$\left( \int_{B(x,t)}|u^*|^{2(p-1)} dy \right)^\frac{1}{2}\leq C\lVert u\rVert_{L^\infty}^{p-4}$$
>   where $u^*(y):=u(y,t-|y-x|)$ (which shouldn't be that relevant I think).

This is for $n=3$, so for any $p\geq 1$, $p^*$ is given by $\frac{1}{p^*}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{3}$.

Here's a compact version of the Theorem he's referring to:

> $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded & open with $C^1$-boundary, $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. If $k<\frac{n}{p}$, then $u\in L^q(U)$ where $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{k}{n}$ and we have $\lVert u\rVert_{L^q(U)}\leq C\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k,p}(U)}$.

I understand that for $k=1$, $q$ is $p^*$ and I also tried
$$\left( \int_{B(x,t)}|u^*|^{2(p-1)} dy \right)^\frac{1}{2}=||u^*||_{L^{2(p-1)}(B(x,t))}^{p-1}$$
or applying Hölder's inequality to $\lVert {u^*}^{2(p-4)}{u^*}^{2^*}\rVert_{L^1}$, but I don't make any progress towards that $L^\infty$-estimate... He probably uses the Sobolev inequality together with some estimate which was found earlier in the proof, but I don't see anything relevant, so I want to concentrate on the Sobolev inequality first. So my question is:

*How to apply an appropiate Sobolev inequality here if you know that $2(p-1)=2(p-4)+2^*$?*

Comment: You didn't give us all the needed information : In which space is $u$? The page number could help too ;)

Comment: I'm not getting it, because I don't think the two sides of the equation scale the same way.  If you replace $u$ by $\alpha u$ for some scalar $\alpha$, then the left hand side multiplies by $\alpha^{p-1}$, whereas the right hand side multiplies by $\alpha^{p-4}$.

Comment: I didn't provide that space because I'm not even entirely sure which one it is. But I think it's safe to assume $u\in H^1$. The page is 678 (2nd edition), chapter 12.3.3. @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I see why each side scales differently, but what's your conclusion from that?

Comment: If the two sides scale differently, the inequality cannot be true for all $u$.  (However the book might have had a specific $u$ in mind.)

Comment: Yes, this is not an arbitrary $u$ of course (it's the solution of a specific nonlinear wave equation), but I don't (yet) see how that - or anything being said in the proof before that inequality - helps finding the estimate. So I wanted to start by understanding what Evans is implying by stating "$2(p-1)=2(p-4)+2^*$.